# Probability first sample is the smallest

Tags: probability

If you take $N+1$ samples independently from a discrete random variable $X$ with range $1,\dots, 100$, what is the probability that your first sample is smaller than all the others?

For a fixed value $k$ the probability that all the other samples are bigger than it is $(P(X>k))^N$. How do you get from here to the  answer?

Are there distributions for $X$ for which there is an answer with a nice asymptotic form?

Comment: what's the distribution of $X$? Uniform?

Comment: @cjferes I don't know it exactly (it is close to normal I think in my applications) but I would like to know what you would have to do if you did know it.

Comment: Do you want to count a sample as the smallest if it is tied for smallest, as in $(1,1,2,3,4)$? Or do you want this sampling to have no smallest sample?

Comment: @ZackWolske In your example the first sample is not smaller than all the others.

Comment: Yes, just making sure we agree on definitions.

Comment: $\sum_{n=1}^{99}P\left\{ X>n\right\} ^{N}P\left\{ X=n\right\} $ is an expression for it. But not so nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $N \to \infty$, all the terms $P(X>k)^N$ go to $0$, but (assuming all $P(X=k) > 0$) the one that goes slowest is $P(X>0)^N$, so the answer is asymptotic to
$$ P(X=1) P(X > 1)^N = P(X=1) (1 - P(X=1))^N \approx P(X=1) \exp(-N P(X=1))$$

Answer (score 1):

The first sample must be one of the $100$ possible values of $X$, and as you already know the remaining samples will be larger than $k$ with probability $(P(X>k))^N$, you can find the answer by summing over all possible values for the first sample
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{100} P(X=k)(P(X>k))^N
$$
If you know the distribution, you can do some things to simplify or approximate this.