# Probability first sample is the smallest in the continuous case

Tags: probability

If you take $N+1$ samples independently from a  continuous random variable $Y$ with range $[0,1]$, what is the probability that your first sample is smaller than all the others?  Let us assume that the pdf of $Y$ is positive in the full range.

In [Probability first sample is the smallest](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/902200/probability-first-sample-is-the-smallest) I asked the same question but for a discrete random variable $X$ in the range $1,\dots,100$. The answer was

$$
\sum_{k=1}^{100} P(X=k)(P(X>k))^N
$$

As $Y$ is continuous I feel the answer in my new question is just $1/(N+1)$ as it is equally likely that any of the samples turns out to be the smallest.

I am confused however.

> How can we get $1/(N+1)$ as a continuous limit of the discrete case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the continuous case it's going to be just this:

$$\begin{align}
\Pr(Y_1 = \min\{Y_k\}) & = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_Y(y)\cdot(1-F_Y(y))^{N}\operatorname{d} y 
\\ & = \int_0^1 (1-F_Y(y))^{N}\operatorname{d} F_Y(y) & \text{as }f_Y(y)\operatorname{d}y=\operatorname{d}F_Y(y)
\\ & = \left[-\frac{(1-F_Y(y))^{N+1}}{N+1}\right]_{F_Y(y)=0}^{F_Y(y)=1}
\\ & = \frac{1}{N+1}
\end{align}$$

Which as you surmised is not surprising.  In any set of **independent and identically distributed** continuous random variables, one of them will be the minimum value, and it is equally likely to be the first one.

Comment: This is exactly the sort of answer I was looking for. But I was hoping not to have to assume the $Y_k$ are uniform.

Comment: @Lembik.  Ah!  I misread the question.  Fortunately you don't have to assume that and it was an easy fix.